# Ldap queries with multiple domains

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, domaincontroller

I have question about LDAP queries and DC in general (in Microsoft AD):

1. Does a DC can contain only one domain? or sub domain can be also on it?
2. Does sub-domain reside in a separate DC?
3. if i want to get data from multiple domain/sub domains what are the ways to get all user, groups and relationship between them using LDAP queries (not using GC and without referrals) ? is the only way to do a separate LDAP query to every DC ?

Thanks

waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

Domain controllers are in charge of a single domain and holds information only about this single domain. Global Catalogs hold information about selected attributes of users and groups of all the forest (master domain and all its subdomains), so the easiest way is to run the query against a GC. Those never respond with referrals.

Every single domain controller can be configured to be a Global Catalog if needed. GC endpoint runs on port 3268 for LDAP and 3269 for LDAPS, so chances are that executing your regular LDAP(S) query against GC ports will result in what you wish. You can get the list of all GCs in the forest by querying DNS for SRV records, i.e. `nslookup -type=SRV _gc._tcp.<forest name>`.